# Proving that if $E_1\subseteq[a,b]$ is measurable and $\mu(E_2) = 0$, then $E_1\cup E_2$ is also measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-measure

> Prove that if $E_1\subseteq[a,b]$ is measurable and $\mu(E_2) = 0$, then $E_1\cup E_2$ is also measurable.

I've unfortunately been stuck on this problem for quite some time (here $\mu$ denotes the measure of a set and $|\cdot|$ denotes the length of an open set).

I wanted to do the proof by contradiction, i.e., suppose that $\mu(E_1\cup E_2)$ is not measurable, i.e. $\mu_*(E_1\cup E_2) < \mu^*(E_1\cup E_2)$. Here's what I know:

- $\mu(E_2) = 0 \implies \mu(E_2^c) = b-a$,
- If $K\subseteq[a,b]$, then $\mu^*(K) + \mu_*(K^c) = b-a$,
- A set $K\subseteq[a,b]$ is measurable if and only if $\mu^*(K) + \mu^*(K^c) \le b-a$,

Obviously the goal here would be to somehow use the assumption that $\mu_*(E_1\cup E_2) < \mu^*(E_1\cup E_2)$ to gain a contradiction, but I'm not sure where the contradiction could even come from using the above facts. Could anyone provide a hint?

---

I can create a self-contained proof using incredibly long-winded lemmas. We get a much stronger result too, showing that $E_1\cap E_2$ is measurable as well. However, this is overkill in a lot of respects:

**PROOF**: Let $\epsilon >0$ be given. Choose open sets $G_1,G_2$ such that $E_1\subseteq G_1, E_2\subseteq G_2$ and $$\mu (G_1) < \mu^*(E_1) + {\epsilon\over2},$$ $$\mu (G_2) < m^*(E_2) + {\epsilon\over2}.$$ Then $$\begin{align}|G_1\cup G_2| + |G_1\cap G_2| &= |G_1| + |G_2|\\ &< \mu^*(E_1) + \mu^*(E_2) + \epsilon\\ \implies\mu^*(E_1\cup E_2) + \mu^*(E_1\cap E_2) &\le \mu^*(E_1) + \mu^*(E_2) \tag{$\epsilon$ is arbitrary}\\ &= \mu(E_1) \tag{$\mu(E_2) = 0$}.\end{align}$$

Of course, $$\begin{align}\mu(E_1) &\ge \mu^*(E_1\cup E_2) + \mu^*(E_1\cap E_2)\\ &\ge \mu_*(E_1\cup E_2) + \mu_*(E_1\cap E_2)\\ &\ge \mu(E_1) + \mu(E_2) \tag{$*$}\\ &= \mu(E_1),\end{align}$$

where $(*)$ will basically be a similar argument to the beginning we can create to show the listed step is valid. Hence, $\mu(E_1) = \mu(E_1\cup E_2) + \mu(E_1\cap E_2)$ utilizing the fact that $\mu_*(\cdot) \le \mu^*(\cdot)$.

Obviously this argument could use some work, and I feel like this can be proven much easier by doing proof by contradiction.

Comment: Use the monotonicity of the inner measure and the subadditivity of the outer measure.